# How to copy files into folders with the creation dates as folder names?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I want to copy photos from the memory card into sub-folders on computer file system, each of the sub-folder name is the creation date of the photos.

I need a Windows command or batch file or simple script, by which I can copy the photo files into corresponding sub-folders by providing the source folder and target folder. The sub-folders should be created under the target folder automatically using the creation dates of the photo files from the source folder.

Answer (score 1):

The following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*) do (
    set a=%%~tf
    echo !a:~0,4!-!a:~5,2!-!a:~8,2!
)
```

will display the date of each file in the current directory in a format suitable for making it part of a filename, assuming that you have set the default date format on your machine to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  If not, you will need to change it a little bit, type `help set` at the command prompt to get information about exactly how that jibberish works. (Keep in mind that I am using `!`s instead of `%`s for delayed expansion, but the examples given by the help use `%`s instead.)

I assume you know how to take it from there.

Comment: To avoid the infamous date format problem, you may directly use the string returned by the %%~t modifier.

Comment: @PA. Nope, because it may contain slashes.

Comment: @PA. actually, let me be more clear about this. If you have ISO 8601, then yes, you can use `%%~tf`. But I suppose the OP does not, that's why I gave him the string extraction example. Now, the string extraction example would have to assume some format, and I chose ISO 8601 because I love it.